# How to setup setInteval so it applies to specific subclasses

Tags: javascript

I have a class called MovingThing that is extended by a class called Monster. Each monster needs its own setinterval timing. Here is what I am using:

GameBoard.js

```
this.monsters = [
        new Monster(this, 'monster_0'),
        new Monster(this, 'monster_1'),
        new Monster(this, 'monster_2')
        ]
```

movingThings.js

```
class Monster extends MovingThing{
constructor(gameboard, dom_id) {
    super('monster', 20, document.getElementById(dom_id), gameboard);
}

class MovingThing {

characterType = '';
speed = 0;
dom = null;
gameBoard = null;
step = 4;
direction = 0;
gameLoop = null
size = 40;
x = 0;
y = 0;
sprite = {
    left: 0,
    right:0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0
};

constructor(characterType, speed, dom, gameboard) {
    this.characterType = characterType;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dom = dom;
    this.gameBoard = gameboard;

    self = this;
    this.gameLoop = setInterval(function(){self.moveLoop()}, this.speed);
}

moveLoop(){
    if (!this.gameBoard.is_active) return;
    //if (this.characterType == 'monster') console.log(this.x, this.y)
    switch (this.direction) {
        case 37:
            this.sprite.left -= 2;
            break;
        case 40:
            this.sprite.top += 2;
            break;
        case 39:
            this.sprite.left += 2;
            break;
        case 38:
            this.sprite.top -= 2;
            break;
    }

    this.drawSprite();
     if (this.sprite.left % this.size === 0  &&
          this.sprite.top % this.size === 0  ){
        this.x = this.sprite.left / this.size;
        this.y = this.sprite.top / this.size;
        this.handleIntersection();
    }
    // console.log(this.direction)
}

setPosition(grid_x, grid_y){
    this.x = grid_x;
    this.y = grid_y;
    this.sprite.top = grid_y * this.size;
    this.sprite.left = grid_x * this.size;
    this.drawSprite();
}

drawSprite(){
    this.sprite.bottom = this.sprite.top + this.size;
    this.sprite.right = this.sprite.left + this.size;

    this.dom.style.top = this.gameBoard.gameBoardPosition.top + this.sprite.top + 'px';
    this.dom.style.left = this.gameBoard.gameBoardPosition.left +  this.sprite.left + 'px';
};

}
```

What happens is only the last monster moves and it moves 3x as fast as it is supposed to. Like there are 3 timers running, but they all move the same monster.

Other than this code, I tried putting the setinterval  in the Monster constructor, but there was the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `self` is global so you keep overwriting it. Use `let` to scope it to the function:

```
let self = this;
this.gameLoop = setInterval(function(){self.moveLoop()}, this.speed);
```

Comment: @aw04 Thanks. This was a big mistake in how JavaScript was designed.